# Is there a better way of using GROUP_CONCAT() for this specific query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, subquery, concatenation

**Problem with Taxonomies in WordPress**

Dealing with Wordpress & WooCommerce taxonomies came up with some problems.
At least i want four tables giving me the correct data i need. My knowledge about MYSQL is very basic - after reading 2 days i can't figure how to write the correct query!

**Database**

```
woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| attribute_id   | attribute_name   | attribute_label |
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+
|              7 | height           | Height          |
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+
|              2 | color            | Color           |
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+

term_taxonomy
+------+------------------+-----------------+
| id   | taxonomy         | term_id         |
+------+------------------+-----------------+
|   36 | pa_color         | 30              |
+------+------------------+-----------------+
|   36 | pa_height        | 31              |
+------+------------------+-----------------+

terms
+---------+-------------+
| term_id | name        |
+---------+-------------+
|      72 | Group 1     |
+---------+-------------+
|      73 | Group 2     |
+---------+-------------+


termmeta
+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| term_id | meta_id   | meta_key        | meta_value |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
|      66 |        72 | _wcga_taxonomie |          7 |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
|      67 |        72 | _wcga_taxonomie |          2 |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
|      68 |        73 | _wcga_taxonomie |          2 |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
```

**My Query**

This is, how my query looks like..

```
SELECT tm.term_id
     , meta_id
     , name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_label) AS wc_attr_label
     , GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) AS wc_attr_tax
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}termmeta AS tm
  JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms AS t 
    ON t.term_id = tm.term_id
  JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies AS wct 
    ON wct.attribute_id = tm.meta_value
 WHERE tm.meta_key = '_wcga_taxonomie'
 GROUP 
    BY t.term_id
```

**Results from above query**

```
Array
(
    [grouped_attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 72
                    [meta_id] => 66
                    [name] => Gruppe 1
                    [wc_attr_label] => Height,Color
                    [wc_attr_tax] => 7,2
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 73
                    [meta_id] => 68
                    [name] => Gruppe 2
                    [wc_attr_label] => Color
                    [wc_attr_tax] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

personally i don't like the way of using GROUP_CONCAT it think it would be much better having all values accessible easy and clean as possible.

Is it possible to set additional object(s) wrapped in an array inside [attributes] without doing another query?

**What i need?**

```
Array
(
    [grouped_attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 72
                    [meta_id] => 66
                    [name] => Group 1
                    [attributes] => Array( Data from woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies )
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 73
                    [meta_id] => 68
                    [name] => Group 2
                    [attributes] => Array( Data from woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies )

                )

        )

)
```

If anybode has some better ideas how to do this, i would really appreciate it!

**EDIT**
Additional Information

> MySQL Version -> 5.6.38nmm-1log
>
> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY no idea how to check this, i'm reading atm!

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `d02dbcff`.`a335s_termmeta`; 

SELECT `meta_id`
     , `term_id`
     , `meta_key`
     ,  LEFT(`meta_value`, 256) 
  FROM `d02dbcff`.`a335s_termmeta` 
 LIMIT 1000;
 
SHOW CREATE TABLE `d02dbcff`.`a335s_terms`; 

SELECT * 
  FROM `d02dbcff`.`a335s_terms` 
 LIMIT 1000;

SHOW CREATE TABLE `d02dbcff`.`a335s_term_taxonomy`; 
SELECT `term_taxonomy_id`
     , `term_id`
     , `taxonomy`
     ,  LEFT(`description`,256)
     , `parent`
     , `count` 
  FROM `d02dbcff`.`a335s_term_taxonomy` 
 LIMIT 1000;

SHOW CREATE TABLE `d02dbcff`.`a335s_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`;
SELECT * 
  FROM `d02dbcff`.`a335s_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`
 LIMIT 1000;
```

**Provided MCVE**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5aa11/5

Comment: i would suggest reading [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) as that is generally not the way how you would use GROUP BY in SQL, And check if your server runs sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` then the server can use [functionally dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get the correct data

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks like i've misunderstood using GROUP_BY, so i definetly have to read more about. Using it as in my example helped me getting rid of duplicates. Never mind MySQL drive me crazy :)

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for also providing expected results based on the example data.. O the table structure also might be important use`SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question.. Also we need to know the MySQL version with `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT need form any part of the answer - leastwise when a presentation layer is available.

Comment: sorry for the lack of information - just jumped into mysql. I want write better code and keep things clean, but its difficult to find examples matching my needs!

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to my question, not sure if it is short enough but it fits exactly my situation.